# Javascript how to assign value to undefined object key?

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to programatically assign values to 'not yet' initialized key in object, like below:

```
const a = {};
// year, month, date is a variable
a[year][month][date] = some data;
```

I know above wouldn't work unless I assign `year` and `month` before assigning to date key,

but I am assigning this programatically so I can't do something like

```
a:{
  2020:{
    10:{
      3: some data
    }
  }
}
```

manually like this.

What would be the best way to assign value to undefined key?

Comment: _"What would be the best way to assign value to undefined key?"_ -> _"...unless I assign year and month before assigning to date key,"_

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that.

You would need to so something like:

```
a[year] = {}
a[year][month] = {}
a[year][month][date] = 'some data';
```

You could use some function like this:

```
function setByPath(obj, path, value) {
    var parts = path.split('.');
    var o = obj;
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
          if (!o[parts[i]])
              o[parts[i]] = {};
          o = o[parts[i]];
      }
    }

    o[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
}
```

Usage:

```
setByPath(a, 'year.month.date', 'some data');
```

Please note that this function is only as an example, and it can cause problems in certain cases. It is to show the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about assigning the previous keys first like you did, but code looks untidy hence asked a question. Guess I have no other ways to do it. By the way, though I declared a as `const`, since I am directly assigning to the properties of a, I am still able to change its value. I guess you are wrong there?

Comment: True, my mistake, I removed that side comment. Ofc you can do that that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the keys without the last one for assigning the value.

```js
const 
    assign = (object, [...keys], value) => {
        const last = keys.pop();
        keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, object)[last] = value
    },
    a = {};

assign(a, [2020, 10, 3], 42);

console.log(a);
```